# Get SimpleDB attribute without looping through all attributes for an item

Tags: c#, amazon-simpledb

I would like to check an attribute using C# and SimpleDB without having to loop through all the attributes for a specific item.

For example, if I have my domain: "MyDomain", and I have three attributes for an item (the item is: george@george.com).

The three attributes are:

Name
Signup
Contacts

So for example this is my data:

MyDomain (domain)
  george@george.com (item)
 
    George Doe (attribute)
    3-1-12 (attribute)
    mike@mike.com (attribute)

The problem I am having is my code will loop through all 3 attributes in the george@george.com item.
 For example; when I run my code the output is:

No Contacts Found
No Contacts Found
Contact: mike@mike.com

because my code is looping through all 3 attributes for the george@george.com item.

I want to make my C# code only check the "Contacts" attribute and NOT loop through all the attributes for the george@george.com item.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

```
AmazonSimpleDB sdb = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleDBClient();

            String selectExpression = "Select * From MyDomain Where Email = 'george@george.com'";
            SelectRequest selectRequestAction =
                new SelectRequest().WithSelectExpression(selectExpression);
            SelectResponse selectResponse = sdb.Select(selectRequestAction);

            if (selectResponse.IsSetSelectResult())
            {
                SelectResult selectResult = selectResponse.SelectResult;
                foreach (Item item in selectResult.Item)
                {

                    foreach (Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute attribute in item.Attribute)
                    {    
                        if (attribute.IsSetName())
                        {

                            if (attribute.Name == "Contact")
                            {
                                if (attribute.IsSetValue())
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Contact: {0}", attribute.Value);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No Contacts Found");
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want it to directly just check the "Contacts" attribute to see if there is a value for it and not loop through all the attributes.

Can someone show me a C# code example on how I would accomplish this?  Thanks.

EDIT:  I still want to loop through all the "Contacts" in the "Contacts" attribute.  I just don't want to loop through all the attributes that don't have the name "Contacts".  The "Contacts" attribute can hold more than one contact and I still need to get all of those from the attribute.

This line of code from Ken below:
 string value = item.Attribute.First(a => a.Name == "Contact").Value

stops the looping of the different attributes, but it only returns 1 contact from the "Contacts" attribute even though there are more than 1 contact stored in the "Contacts" attribute.

Comment: You can try `string value = item.Attribute.First(a => a.Name == "Contact").Value` if you *know* it is there or `FirstOrDefault` and check the result.

Comment: That works to stop the looping, but if there are multiple Contacts in the "Contacts" attribute, it only returns the first contact.  I still want to loop through all the different contacts in the "Contacts" attribute, I just don't want to loop through all the different attributes with names other than "Contacts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Amazon simpleDB Query with Attribute.

```
select <attribute_name> from <domain_name>
```

And Amazon SimpleDB will return only items that have this attribute and in response you will get only this attribute even items have other attributes.